# Ошибка при запуске проекта React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, react-native

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\anton\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-30T11_49_52_841Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\anton\Documents\React\mydemo>
```

После того как запускаю проект через тепминал VSCode через команду "npm start"
Выдает такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.14.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prestart: @
6 info lifecycle @~start: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\anton\Documents\React\mydemo\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;E:\Selenium Driver JAVA\chromeDriver;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;E:\Soft\Genymobile\Genymotion;C:\Users\anton\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\anton\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git;C:\Users\anton\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: C:\Users\anton\Documents\React\mydemo
10 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `expo start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\anton\Documents\React\mydemo
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.14.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ start: `expo start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Откройте файл лога. Выложите ошибку.

Comment: Выложил ошибку в логе

Comment: А что выдаст эта команда `expo --version`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Удалите папку `node_modules` из корня проекта. Затем в терминале выполните npm install
2. Если первый пункт не помог, то удалите `node_modules`, удалите `Node`, удалите все файлы которые остались от `Node` а именно папку `npm` в `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\`